# "Given a convex quadrilateral ABCD."

Tags: geometry

> Given a convex quadrilateral ABCD. Points K and L are the means
>   commensurate of sides AB and CD. Prove that if the field quadrangles
>   BCLK and DAKL are equal, the quadrilateral ABCD is a trapezoid.

I don't know how to solve that. Please give me hints and 
solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint:

Draw the segments $CK$ and $DK$, and argue about the triangles so generated.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me more ?

Comment: Next step: The triangles $\Delta(DLK)$ and $\Delta(CLK)$ have the same area.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can I ask you for the next step :) ?

Comment: Next step: The triangles $\Delta(ADK)$ and $\Delta(BCK)$ have the same area.

Comment: Ok, and then we can see that : ...

Comment: can you give me more hints  ? I have only one day to give a solution. Thanks

Comment: Next step: The triangles $\Delta(ADK)$ and $\Delta(BCK)$ have the same horizontal base length and the same area.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me one more hint please ...

Comment: The area of a triangle is ${1\over2}\cdot b\cdot h$ where $b$ is the base length and $h$ is the height.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you continue ?

Comment: Next step: The triangles $\Delta(ADK)$ and $\Delta(BCK)$ have the same height. – This is my last word in this matter;  I should have stopped this ordeal days ago.